# Windows flags Microsoft Sysinternals .zip files as malicious

Tags: malware, windows, virus, antivirus, antimalware

Downloaded sdelete v2.01 from official Microsoft website using Google Chrome on Windows 10 Pro: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete

Basic info for SDelete.zip:

SHA256: e78fe7d61b760118529858351c20e2814d5ca8a0c16e7c65fd180fd12f431824
Size: 161107 bytes
Scan: [Virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/e78fe7d61b760118529858351c20e2814d5ca8a0c16e7c65fd180fd12f431824/detection)

Then tried to unzip the zip-file and got message "Windows found that this file is potentially harmful. To help protect your computer, Windows has blocked access to this file."

1) Why Windows detects this file as harmful?

2) How to fix this problem?

3) Does anyone get same warning with this file?

[image: Windows Security Warning]

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with this specific file, and everything to do that it's a zip file downloaded from the Internet.

Open the properties for the zip file, and you should see an option for unblocking [like in the screenshot below] near the bottom of the `General` tab.   Unblock the file, and you should be able to unzip it.

[image]